# No top-level getter '_registerPlugins' declared

Tags: flutter, save, nosuchmethoderror

When I save my code after changing any code on VSCode, I get this error;

[image]

It doesn't stop my emulator from keep running, but I think there's something missing or some mistakes about my app. What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Flutter and has already been fixed.

see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77680#issuecomment-818296447